# Sorting Coordinate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I having trouble sorting a coordinate list

Original coordinates:

```
[(229, 42), (159, 42), (50, 42), (114, 6), (52, 6), (308, 5), (193, 3)]
```

I am using following code to do the sorting.

```
sorted(coordinates , key=lambda k: [k[0], k[1]],reverse=False)
```

current coordinate after sorted

[image]

```
[(50, 42), (52, 6), (114, 6), (159, 42), (193, 3), (229, 42), (308, 5)]
```

But I want the 
Coordinates in this way

[image]

```
[(52, 6), (114, 6), (193, 3), (308, 5), (50, 42), (159, 42), (229, 42) ]
```

Any suggestion how to do this?
I tried sorting by x then follow by y but the result is not what i wanted.

Comment: How are those co-ordinates rendered? With those numbers and diagram provided it isn't clear as to what is being attempted.

Comment: Please provide the original `coordinates` list

Comment: @shash678 Hi i added the original coordinates.

Comment: @PatrickArtner `(x, y)`, which is why `(52, 6), (114, 6)` before `(193, 3)`

Comment: if you sort a list of tuples `(x,y)` by x and then by y this is the **default result** when sorting lists of tuples. They get sorted by the 1st element of each tuple, if the 1st element ties (equal) those that tie are ordered by the 2nd element. I do not get how you can have `[(52, 6), (114, 6), (193, 3), (308, 5), (50, 42), (159, 42), (229, 42) ]` as `(50, 42)` has clearly the lowest `x`and should come first.  Your testdata does not contain _any_ ties, so its simply sorted by `x` which makes `[(50, 42), (52, 6), (114, 6), (159, 42), (193, 3), (229, 42), (308, 5)]` the correct result.

Comment: @PatrickArtner  `[(52, 6), (114, 6), (193, 3), (308, 5), (50, 42), (159, 42), (229, 42) ]` is the result I want. I know `[(50, 42), (52, 6), (114, 6), (159, 42), (193, 3), (229, 42), (308, 5)]` is the correct result. Which is why I looking for solution to get the result I wanted instead.

Comment: **You** have to supply your sorting criterias, show us an algorithmic way to come from your input to your output. The only other way we would be able to help you is by telling you to hardcode your wanted result - if you cannot communicate which criterias to use to get from **input** to **wanted output ** - how should we be able help? Your screenshot does not help _at all_ to help us help you - there is no connection between your coordinates and your images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to sort by area, which means simply multiply the numbers together, e.g.:

```
In []:
sorted(coordinates , key=lambda k: k[0]*k[1])

Out[]:
[(52, 6), (193, 3), (114, 6), (308, 5), (50, 42), (159, 42), (229, 42)]
```

Note: do you have `(114, 6)` and `(193, 3)` out of order - if not then it is some other sort function.

I can force the order the OP is looking for by some stretched euclidian distance calculation, but this is completely arbitrary:

```
In []:
import math
sorted(c, key=lambda k: math.hypot(k[0]/5, k[1]*5))

Out[]:
[(52, 6), (114, 6), (193, 3), (308, 5), (50, 42), (159, 42), (229, 42)]
```

Comment: Hi, I not try to sort by area.

Comment: Then you need to describe what is the algorithm you are trying to sort by... you will need some calculation on `k[0]` and `k[1]` that will return a lower number for order the you describe. Sorting by `k[0]` and `k[1]` directly cannot give you the order you describe.

Comment: Euclidian distance calculation is what I wanted. Thank you. The result is indeed arbitrary.